# How to Update Thumbnail preview with Main panel updates in Winforms, Like powerpoint Thumbnail preview?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, powerpoint

I am new to desktop applications. I am working on a solution where I click add button a button will be added to the panel and this process should be displayed at the thumbnail.
    like powerpoint. 
[image: see image]
my app looks like

[image: this]

So when I click add button it adds a button to right panel and its preview would be updated in thumbnail also.

Can we make this in winforms application??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a thumbnail of an inactive C# WPF Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141800/create-a-thumbnail-of-an-inactive-c-sharp-wpf-window)

Comment: But Can we make this in winforms application too??